# How to add colours to a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just created a table in javascript and i'm supposed to make the numbers in the table change color as they increase but I'm getting an error, what do you think the problem with this code is?

```
    var caloriesBurned = weight * i * j

        if ( caloriesBurned <= userBMR*0.25 )
        <td>
        <span class = "black" >; 

        else if( caloriesBurned > userBMR*0.25 && caloriesBurned < userBMR*0.5){
        <td>
<span class="green">;
```

Thank you

Comment: yes, is it all wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is. You are mixing faulty JavaScript with HTML - that's (I'm sorry) a total disaster. If you could provide a https://jsfiddle.net/ with more of your code (like the actual table you want to change), we could try to help better. And please take your time and start reading a bit here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp and move on by clicking "next chapter"

Comment: Stop it, PLEASE PROVIDE a JS-FIDDLE... https://jsfiddle.net/
And then add that created js-fiddle-link to your question... don't use the comment-section for more then one line of code!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgL6unL5/

Comment: It's okay, you are new here... Also if my answer was the solution, please accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your provided fiddle you could add the if/else in the inner loop,
before the "burned calories" are added. Like this:

```
            var caloriesBurned = userWeight * i * j / 2;

            if (caloriesBurned <= userBMR*0.25) {
                tableHTML += "<td style='color: red;'>";
            } else {
                tableHTML += "<td style='color: green;'>";
            }

            tableHTML += caloriesBurned;
            tableHTML += "</td>";
```

I updated your fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/wgL6unL5/1/

Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes it is, also can I ask for one more favour? How can I add a border to the table?

Comment: Around the table, or between the cells, or both?

Comment: Both around the table and between the cells

Comment: Oh you did, perfect. Have a nice day and consider reading a little more about what you are doing :)

Comment: Last one, so I made one adjustment to the javascript and I don't know what I did wrong but its not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgL6unL5/3/

Comment: On jsfiddle, after you change something, you have to click at the top on "update" to create a new 'version' of that fiddle with your changes...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgL6unL5/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgL6unL5/5/

Comment: You moved it outside the inner-loop. So after the loop you are just adding 1 td-element. If you still want to influence the colors of cell-values, you must put your code inside the loop where you create the td. Only before that moment, but inside the inner-loop, you can set the color of each cell.